# Makefile: execute notification command if any build step has been run

Tags: shell, makefile, build

I have started using `make` for compiling assets (TypeScript, Sass) and installing/executing dependencies (PHP composer, Node npm, clearing caches) for local website development and in build pipelines.

I would like a notification whenever anything new has been finished building. The terminal bell (`tput bel`) is simple and my terminal nicely converts it to a desktop notification if it is not in focus.

But since a build job can consist of multiple targets I do not want to just run it in the recipe of each target but only when `make` has finished.

Is there a syntax/trick (within a `Makefile`, I want to avoid an external wrapper script)  to have a command executed after all build jobs have run? Maybe even a possibility to run a different command if anything was not successful?

Comment: No, there is nothing like that.

Comment: agree with @MadScientist. But if your reason for not wanting a wrapper script or extra command is simply having to type more - you can always create an alias. (alias makeit='make; if [ $?  == 0 ]; then #success ; else #fail ; fi'